# Do any Google Voice APIs still work?

Tags: api, voice

I am interested in writing a simple CLI program that will send an SMS using Google Voice.

There are several scripts and an API or two available, but I have run into an issue that none of them seem to work any longer; as they mostly rely on parsing returned web pages.

Is anyone familiar with a current API that works so that I can send an SMS on Google Voice?

Thanks!

Comment: (Shameless self promotion) Save yourself the hassle. All of those scripts are temporary workarounds for violating the GV Terms of Service. Why not just use a gateway? (see profile for my recommendation)

Comment: Call me crazy, but I don't see anything relevant in your profile.  I even gave a good ol' google search of *your* site without luck. [edit] do you mean twilio?  Pretty sweet $30 credit = 3000 free text messages.  Is there an expiration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google Voice changed the login procedure, and it now expects you to pass back a cookie. This issue for the Python wrapper sums it up: http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/issues/detail?id=60

**UPDATE AND FIX:** Actually all that needs to happen is to change the login URL in your code:
Old URL - https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=grandcentral
New URL - https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=grandcentral